# Unable to get value in payumoney success response, which is passed from controller method

Tags: php, codeigniter, payumoney

I have integrated payumoney payment gateway in my project and it was working fine, but I have additional requirements so I want to pass is an id. I am getting the ID like this '$this->input->post('id'), and assign it the variable $plan_info and pass it to the confirmation page(view page), when the user clicks on the confirm button, the payment will be done by debit/netbanking. In the success page, I am not getting $plan_info value however I am passing to the confirmation page.

**Code written in controller**

```
    $product_info = 'testTransaction';
    $customer_name = $this->input->post('customer_name');
    $customer_email = $this->input->post('customer_email');
    $customer_mobile = $this->input->post('mobile_number');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $customer_address = $this->input->post('customer_address');
    $MERCHANT_KEY = "xyz"; 
    $SALT = "xyzxyz";   
    $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
    //optional udf values 
    $udf1 = '';
    $udf2 = '';
    $udf3 = '';
    $udf4 = '';
    $udf5 = ''; 
    $hashstring = $MERCHANT_KEY . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $product_info . '|' . $customer_name . '|' . $customer_email  . '|'. $udf1 . '|' . $udf2 . '|' . $udf3 . '|' . $udf4 . '|' . $udf5 . '||||||' . $SALT; 
    $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hashstring));
    $success = base_url() . 'Success';
    $fail = base_url() . 'Success';
    $cancel = base_url() . 'Success';
    $data = array(
        'mkey' => $MERCHANT_KEY,
        'tid' => $txnid,
        'hash' => $hash,
        'amount' => $amount,
        'name' => $customer_name,
        'productinfo' => $product_info,
        'mailid' => $customer_email,
        'phoneno' => $customer_mobile,
        'address' => $customer_address,
        'action' => "https://test.payu.in", //for live change action  
         https://secure.payu.in
        'sucess' => $success,
        'failure' => $fail,
        'cancel' => $cancel,
        'plan_info'=>$id // This value which is passed to confirm page should get back in payment success response 
    );
    $this->load->view('confirmation', $data);
```

**code  written in view file**

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>/_payment" method="post" id="payuForm" name="payuForm">
                        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $mkey; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash; ?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $tid; ?>" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Total Payable Amount</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>"  readonly/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Your Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" readonly/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $mailid; ?>" readonly/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phoneno; ?>" readonly />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"> Booking Info</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo $productinfo; ?>" readonly />

                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="plan_info" value="<?php echo $plan_info; ?>"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="address1" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" readonly/>     
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="surl" value="<?php echo $sucess; ?>" size="64" type="hidden" />
                            <input name="furl" value="<?php echo $failure; ?>" size="64" type="hidden" />  
                            <!--for test environment comment  service provider   -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" />

                            <input name="curl" value="<?php echo $cancel; ?> " type="hidden" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group float-right">
                            <input type="submit" value="Pay Now" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
```

**My requirement**

1) How do I pass the value inside udf1 (If I pass in `$udf1` then I am getting a checksum error).
2) If the `$planinfo` variable passed separately (not in `$udf1`) then how to get that value in success page (I have tried `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); exit();`) all values are getting except `$plan_info` value.

So how do I get plan info value and how can I pass in any value in uf1 without getting a checksum error

Answer (score 0):

1. assign the $udf1 = $id before $hashstring
2. Pass the $udf1 value in $data array eg

   $data =array('udf1' => $id,..)
3. Add/Pass the udf1 value in view page also.

Comment: I tried  what u told but getting error   checksum error message

Comment: Checksum Failed  after doing like this  $udf1 = $id; before converting to hashstring

Comment: what about 'udf1' in posted value?

Comment: If I keep value in $udf1/$udf2/$udf3/$udf4  and when click on pay now payment failed and getting   'Checksum Failed ' error